# Get JSON array from Ext.data.Store outside?

Tags: grid, extjs

How can I get JSON array from Ext.data.Store outside the function?
The code:

```
var store = new Ext.data.Store({
                model: 'nested' + type,
                proxy: {
                    type: 'ajax',
                    url: '/Grid/GetDetailed?InvoiceId=' + $(row).attr('id'),
                    reader: {
                        type: 'json',
                        root: 'items',
                        totalProperty: 'totalCount'
                    }
                }
            });
            store.load();
```

And I want to use something like this:

```
store.getAt(0);
```

but it's undefined.
someone said it beacaouse of the ajax which is asynchronic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use store.getAt(0) immediately after the store.load() is called then yes, the problem is that the load is asynchronic so you should use the callback method of the load to fix this.

```
store.load({
    scope   : this,
    callback: function(records, operation, success) {
        //here the store has been loaded so you can use what functions you like
        store.getAt(0);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Ext.create](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext-method-create) instead of `new` keyword when creating the store, and define a [storeId](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.AbstractStore-cfg-storeId) for the store. Then you can use [Ext.getStore()](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext-method-getStore) method to retrieve the store.

Comment: Is the `store` itself undefined, or does the `getAt(0)` call return an undefined record? In the latter case, the reason is probably what @nscrob wrote. You need to ensure the store is loaded before attempting to access its contents.

Answer (score 0):

You can also make it work by doing the following:

```
//This function will be called only after the store has been loaded successfully.
store.on('load',function(this, records, successful, eOpts){
     store.getAt(0);
}, this);
```